# as2: __FILE__ equivalent in flash (how to find the file name of the current running application)

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

i wrote an swf application using action script 2,
i want to be able to know the file name of the current running swf file.

i know that in php i have `__FILE__` to get current running php file, is there something like that in flash?

Comment: is this running standalone, as an air app or in a webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `stage.loaderInfo.url` variable for AS3 and `this._url` or `_root._url` (if you're not in root already) for AS2

Comment: when i try to trace(stage.loaderInfo.url) using adobe flash it returns undefined.

Comment: Are you running AS2 or AS3? That should work in an ActionScript 3 project.

Comment: working with action script 2. i should have noted that before, updating main post. thanks